# Call display value for choices with SQL

Tags: sql, django

I'm wanting to write SQL for a Django field that uses `CharField(choices=())` and have the display value show up in the SQL rather than the call value. Any idea how to do this? It's similar to [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

For reference's sake, here's my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    STUDENT_CHOICES=(
        (0,'None'),
        (1,'UA Current LDP'),
        (2,'UA LDP Alumni'),
        (3,'MSU Current LDP'),
        (4,'MSU LDP Alumni')
    )
    ...
    studentStatus=models.IntegerField(choices=STUDENT_CHOICES, verbose_name="Student Status", null=True, blank=True)
```

And my query:

```
def mailingListQuery(request):
...
if request.POST:
    ...
    sql = """
        ...
        per."studentStatus" # Here's where I want to access the display value
        left outer join person as per on (per.party_id = p.id)
    """
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The display value is just that - a display value. It's not stored in your database and therefore you can't access it with SQL.

Comment: Why you want to use display value? I think it is not a good approach

Comment: @szaman My users want to be able to pull a CSV that is human-readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
STUDENT_CHOICES=(
    ('None', 'None'),
)
```

Also, avoid using raw SQL. If you really need it - always use parametrized queries

connection.cursor().execute('sql with %s params', [params])